# Animation not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Can somebody tell me why blink effect is not working chrome browser

```
<p class="blink">at least it's not Comic Sans</p>
<style>

.blink {
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-name: blink;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: steps(2, start);
}
@keyframes blink {
80% {
    visibility: hidden;
}
}

</style>
```

And also I require this to work on every iOS and Android devices.  Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing -webkit prefixes for animation and keyframes.

First of all, for reference, please do try out this:[Tryit from W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation4)

Especially in chrome, things such as animation, transformation requires -webkit prefix. After reading my reference, you should be able to do it yourself.

But here is the solution anyway. See result here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f28f4/)

```
.blink {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-name: blink;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, start);

animation-duration: 1s;
animation-name: blink;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: steps(2, start);
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
80% {
    visibility: hidden;
}
}

@keyframes blink {
80% {
    visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

You now can go on and read more about prefix (simply search about it google)